# Why does datetime.strptime not work with numpy giving ' float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.datetime' '

Tags: python, numpy, datetime, urllib

I'm trying to get the datetime type to be used in the numpy array (`datep`) here. I have tried to approaches for the function `bytespdates2num`.

First is:

```
    def bytespdates2num(fmt,encoding = 'utf-8'):
        def bytesconverter(b):
            s = b.decode(encoding)
            return mdate.datestr2num(s)
        return bytesconverter
```

Second is:

```
    def bytespdates2num(fmt, encoding = 'utf-8'):
        def bytesconverter(b):
            s = b.decode(encoding)
            return datetime.datetime.strptime(s)
        return bytesconverter
```

My code is:

```
import urllib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np
import ssl
import requests
import json
import datetime

#First or second approach
def bytespdates2num(fmt, encoding = 'utf-8'):
     def bytesconverter(b):
         #makes it into string from utf-8 encoding format
        s  = b.decode(encoding)
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(s,fmt)
     return bytesconverter

url1 = 'https://pythonprogramming.net/yahoo_finance_replacement'
data = urllib.request.urlopen(url1,context = None).read().decode()
stockprices = list()
stocksplitdata = data.split('\n')
for line in stocksplitdata:
    stockprices.append(line)

date,openp,highp,lowp,closep,adjust,vol = np.loadtxt(stockprices[1:],delimiter = ',',\
                                                     unpack = True,\
                                                     converters = {0:bytespdates2num('%Y-%m-%d')})
```

While the first approach works and I can proceed to plot the matplotlib graph using datep as the xaxis, the second approach fails giving `float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.datetime` . However while debugging, running the `datetime.datetime.strptime(s)` line on the command line gives the datetime object of `s` . Why is this occurring? The `datetime` approach too turns a string format date into a date time format and seems more straight forward too.

Comment: I think the problem is  with how you're using the array after you do this. Something else expects column 0 to contain a float, not a datetime.

Comment: I'm not familiar with numpy, but datestr2num returns a value of type `DateNumber` and strptime returns well, a `datetime.datetime` object. maybe that's related? yeah, as @Barmar suggested, it could be how you use the data after.

Comment: @Himal But the error says that something is expecting a `float`, not `DateNumber`, so I don't see how that's relevant.

Comment: Post the full traceback.

Comment: @Barmar Does it specifically say not `DateNumber`? because, I think `DateNumber`  could be easily converted to a number or string. then again, I'm not familiar with numpy package.

Comment: Oh, you're right. It's talking about the argument to the `float()` function, not something expecting a `float`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you specify a converter, you still need to specify a `dtype`.

I tried to recreate your case with a simple input (WHY DIDN'T YOU DO THIS FOR US???)

```
In [20]: txt = """2011-01-23 
    ...: 2020-03-23"""
```

Your second converter (one of your's is missing the `fmt`):

```
In [21]: def bytespdates2num(fmt, encoding = 'utf-8'): 
    ...:         def bytesconverter(b): 
    ...:             s = b.decode(encoding) 
    ...:             return datetime.datetime.strptime(s, fmt) 
    ...:         return bytesconverter 
    ...:
```

Your run, with FULL TRACEBACK!

```
In [22]: np.loadtxt(txt.splitlines(), converters={0:bytespdates2num('%Y-%m-%d')})              
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-56c1854d614f> in <module>
----> 1 np.loadtxt(txt.splitlines(), converters={0:bytespdates2num('%Y-%m-%d')})

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py in loadtxt(fname, dtype, comments, delimiter, converters, skiprows, usecols, unpack, ndmin, encoding, max_rows)
   1159         for x in read_data(_loadtxt_chunksize):
   1160             if X is None:
-> 1161                 X = np.array(x, dtype)
   1162             else:
   1163                 nshape = list(X.shape)

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'
```

The default `dtype` for `loadtxt` is float.  It has `read_data` (as a list of lists), and is now trying to convert it into an array, using the default `dtype`.

If instead I specify `object` as dtype:

```
In [23]: np.loadtxt(txt.splitlines(), converters={0:bytespdates2num('%Y-%m-%d')}, dtype=object)
    ...:                                                                                       
Out[23]: 
array([datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 23, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 23, 0, 0)], dtype=object)
```

Or I could specify a `datetime64` dtype:

```
In [24]: np.loadtxt(txt.splitlines(), converters={0:bytespdates2num('%Y-%m-%d')}, dtype='datetime64[D]')                                                                             
Out[24]: array(['2011-01-23', '2020-03-23'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

Sorry for the caps, but I get tired asking for tracebacks and sample inputs.  Providing those should be mandatory for SO questions.

With `mdates` (not correction in code):

```
In [30]:     def bytespdates2num(fmt,encoding = 'utf-8'): 
    ...:         def bytesconverter(b): 
    ...:             s = b.decode(encoding) 
    ...:             return mdates.datestr2num(s) 
    ...:         return bytesconverter 
    ...:                                                                                       
In [31]: np.loadtxt(txt.splitlines(), converters={0:bytespdates2num('%Y-%m-%d')})              
Out[31]: array([734160., 737507.])
```

Evidently that's returning a number rather than a datatime object.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. It cleared things up for me. With regards to your last point on the mdates returning a number, we can use that format with ```plot_date``` and the number will be formatted as a matplotlib date

Comment: Because we often plot things with a date axis, `matplotlib` expanded on the Python `datetime` module long before `numpy` added the `datatime64` dtype.